# Makefile returns an error when I try to use cl.exe as the compiler

Tags: c++, makefile, cl.exe

I have activated `vcvarsall.bat` in my makefile, however I still get this error when I try compiling my program:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.1
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl /Z7 /W3 C:\Dev\LearningC++\main.cpp
, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [build] Error 2

[Process exited 2]
```

Makefile:

```
all: build run

build: main.cpp
    @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
    @cl /Z7 /W3 C:\Dev\LearningC++\main.cpp

run:
    @bin\main.exe
```

When I type the commands manually, the code does get compiled and I produce and executable which works, however I also get these weird warning messages from the compiler:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MS
VC\14.29.30133\include\ostream(746): warning C4530: C++ exception handler
 used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
main.cpp(4): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std:
:basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_t
raits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char
 *)' being compiled
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I removed the mingw tag because it appears you are using Visual Studio tools, not MinGW tools.

Comment: And your `%PATH%` variable contains the correct directory, where `cl.exe` is installed?  I am afraid, you're giving us not enough information, to help in solving your problem.

Comment: Does it work if you type the commands manually without the makefile?

Comment: Yes, this works if I type the commands manually, however I get a weird warning message from the compiler. I have edited the question and added more information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a makefile recipe, every command line is run in its own shell.  In Windows the `vcvarsall.bat` file sets a bunch of environment variables and environment variables are in effect only for the current shell; when the shell exits they are gone.  When you run:

```
build: main.cpp
    @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
    @cl /Z7 /W3 C:\Dev\LearningC++\main.cpp
```

first make starts a shell and runs the `call` in it which sets the Visual Studio environment, then the shell exits and all those variable settings are lost.  Then make starts another shell and runs `cl` but the environment settings it wants are no longer there so it fails.

I think the way to put multiple commands on a single line in Windows `cmd.exe` is using `&` so you can try rewriting your makefile like this:

```
build: main.cpp
    @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 \
      & cl /Z7 /W3 C:\Dev\LearningC++\main.cpp
```

(note the backslash at the end of the `call` line, then the `&`).